# ROT13 Implementation using Char Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, char, rot13

I'm a newbie programmer who has been working on a ROT13 implementation as part of a tutorial and came across the following code. It outputs the correct characters however I'm not quite sure how it works and there is no explanation attached.

```
char rot13[] = { 'N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M' };
std::string alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length(); i++) {
    std::cout << rot13[alphabet[i] - 'A'];
}
```

Specifically, I dont quite understand how minusing the 'A' from a character within the string alphabet provides us with our ROT13 number. I initially thought that 'A' corresponded to an index within rot13[] and minusing that would provide us with a new index, however wouldn't that indicate that any numbers beneath A's index (Z,Y,X...) would become negative indexes as a result and throw errors.

Is anyone able to explain the logic behind this code to me?

Comment: The example is kind of stupid, because `alphabet[i] - 'A' == i`. So `rot13[i]` would work just as well. Anyway, it relies on the fact that ASCII codes of characters `'A'` through `'Z'` are sequential, so e.g. `'B' == 'A' + 1`. From here it follows that `'B' - 'A' == 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Granted that `alphabet[i]` is an uppercase letter (which is the case in your example), `alphabet[i] - 'A'` will compute the distance to the letter 'A' in the ASCII table. So `'A'-'A'` will be 0, `'B'-'A'` will be 1 and so on, up to `'Z'-'A'` which is 25.

Your character array `rot13` is written so that the index 0 has the letter `'N'`, the index 1 is the letter `'O'` and so on up to index 12 with the letter `'Z'` and then index 13 is `'A'`, index 14 is `'B'` and so on up to index 25 which is `'M'`

To make things clearer, let’s rewrite this line:

```cpp
std::cout << rot13[alphabet[i] - 'A'];
```

As:

```cpp
char letterBeforeRot13 = alphabet[i];
int index = letterBeforeRot13 - 'A';
char letterAfterRot13 = rot13[index];
std::cout << letterAfterRot13;
```

This is pretty much what your compiler does, but with more details.

If we pick an example where `alphabet[i]` equals to the letter `'A'`, `letterBeforeRot13` is assigned to the letter `'A'`, `index` is assigned to `'A'-'A'` which is `0`, `letterAfterRot13` is assigned to the element of the array `rot13` at index `0`, which is `'N'`. So the letter `'A'` is transformed into `'N'`.

You can do the same for any letter and you will see that everything is fine, including the edge cases when you thought that things would be out of bounds. You cannot have negative indexes with this technique.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you for your detailed step-by-step response.

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau, I hesitated about editing it but I thought it was wrong to edit an answer who was already accepted.